# Cannot disable JWT Claims mapping using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear()

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to disable the JWT claims mapping in ASP.NET Core (not sure why it's there in the first  place...) since the new names are much longer than the original ones (for example, instead of a simple `oid` claim, I need to access the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier` one).

According to the docs, this can be done by calling `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear()` as early as possible in the Program.cs file.

However, no matter where I call this method, the claims are still mapped and I still can't access the `oid` claim.

What am I missing? Why doesn't the mapping get disabled?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the mapper map the oid to another claim or you want to build a custom claim to map it?

Comment: Currently the mapper maps the oid to another claim, and I want to disable this, so that oid will be oid in the claims collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `MapInboundClaims` in your `JwtBearerOptions` to `false`.

So, the resulting code in your `Program.cs` should look something like this:

```
builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            //other code

            options.MapInboundClaims = false;
        });
```

Comment: That just fixed my problem when I migrated to dotnet 8. The op's version did work for me so far